# Hide the Javascript in the page source and instead display the content of this script

Tags: javascript

Here is the javas cript call in my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/OrderConfirmationStep/CreateOrderInformGoogleTag"></script>
```

after the corresponding page renders I can able to see this line    in the page source(on right click and view source in the browser). but The requirement is to hide the script and instead I has to display the content of this script.

How can I achieve this ??

Comment: You can't hide hardcode from the source, because that is the source. Using _JavaScript_, you can hide it from "generated source", if you dynamically make the page server side you could do a replacement before the client ever sees it, or you could replace it in the hardcode

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: in the page source,After clicking on the <script type="text/javascript" src="/OrderConfirmationStep/CreateOrderInformGoogleTag"></script> Its showing some content, I want that content directly in the page source (want to avoid one more click to show the cotnent of <script type="text/javascript" src="/OrderConfirmationStep/CreateOrderInformGoogleTag"></script> in the page source )

Comment: You need to change the server-side logic to spit out the JS into the page instead of generating the `script` tag.